# Don't want it to scroll if it fits in height

Tags: html, css

I am designing a left side menu bar vertically listed, using `ul > li`. A Div `(.menu_bar)` contains this menu `ul > li` and it's positioned relative with 100% of height.

**Working perfect**

I want this side menu bar to view by scroll(***not the menubar scroll but body scroll***) if the viewport height is not enough to cover.

**Not Working**

Also i want that if there is extra height available then it should cover the rest height of screen. That means the .menu_bar div must cover rest height.

**Tried so far:**

- Also used **height:100vh** before, but it adds scroll even it has enough height;
- Created [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h8scghLm/2/)

```css
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:auto;
    color:white;
    width:100%;
}
.menu_bar {
    margin:0px;
    position:relative;
    top:56px;
    float:left;
    left:0px;
    min-height:100% !important;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    background:#2c2b39;
    width:auto;
}
.menu_bar ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:auto;
}
.menu_bar ul li {
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent
    /*#03D4D7*/
    ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #22212C;
}
.menu_bar img {
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_bar">
    <ul>
        <li style="border-left: 3px solid #03D4D7; background:#1B1924;">
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Home</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Dashboard</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Log Stats</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Network</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Settings</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `.menu_bar` div is positioned 56px from the top of the document, you can give it a min-height of `calc(100vh - 56px)`, which will make it fill the rest of the screen.

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h8scghLm/4/

**Live Demo**:

```css
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:auto;
    color:white;
    width:100%;
}
.menu_bar {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
    margin:0px;
    position:relative;
    top:56px;
    float:left;
    left:0px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    background:#2c2b39;
    width:auto;
}
.menu_bar ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:auto;
}
.menu_bar ul li {
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center; 
    border-left: 3px solid transparent/*#03D4D7*/; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #22212C; 
}
.menu_bar img {
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_bar">
    <ul>
        <li style="border-left: 3px solid #03D4D7; background:#1B1924;">
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Home</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Dashboard</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Log Stats</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Network</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="home.png" />
            <label>Settings</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes tried it before, but it see if you make view port height such that it does not cover the whole 'menu_bar' div, after try to scroll, you will find it that menu_bar actually does not cover the whole height.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h8scghLm/5/) added border to just check the div. Try to scroll

Comment: @divy3993 I changed my answer a couple minutes ago to use `min-height` instead of `height`. Here's your fiddle, but fixed to use the new answer: http://jsfiddle.net/h8scghLm/6/

Comment: Ok ya almost there, why is the scroll bar still showing up? though no requirement of scroll.

Comment: @divy3993 When you add a border, it adds to the height of the element and makes it so it overflows the window height. Here is an example without the border: http://jsfiddle.net/h8scghLm/7/

Comment: Oh ya my bad, forgot that i added red border just oops.

Comment: Hey also wanna ask you about this, i use media queries, so how to get rid of this min-height for other media queries. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h8scghLm/8/). Please help!

Comment: Here we did was for media query > max-width:960px; but now for 640px. It occupies whole height though i do not want it to.

Comment: @divy3993 To get rid of min-height you can set `min-height: 0` in your media query.